# Role which can add permissions only?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to create a SharePoint role which can only view the data, and give the same permissions to others, however is unable to delete roles.

Or, to restate it, I need a role R1 which if given by user A to user B and C on a document allows user B to view the document and grant R1 to D and E, but does not allow B to remove C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a permission level to do that, however, when you create a new SharePoint group you can define a group owner and configure the group so that the group owner can add users to that group, even when the user is not a site owner.

You can also configure the group so that group members can add other members.
The users will also be able to remove other members from the group, so it doesn't meet your business requirements either.

The only way I see it is with custom development, but dealing with SharePoint permissions is never an easy path.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify what you mean by custom development?

Comment: Hi Akash, a custom WebPart can be developed to implement what you want. You need some SharePoint developer skills in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't such a permission level. If you are able to add users to certain roles, you are also allowed to remove users from (other) roles. Furthermore you are alloewd to create/update/delete all roles.